# Blender closes when I right click in Object mode?

Tags: objects

I've never encountered this issue before but I've finished making a model, created the armature then switched to object mode. Everything is working fine until I right click on the model(or anywhere) then the program just closes.

I tried opening the console window to see if it could tell me what the error/issue is but that closes too so I can't even see if this is a code or what.

Any idea what's causing this and how to fix it?

**Please do not ask me to upload the model, under no condition will I do this due to theft in the past**

I'm using Windows 10 on a MSI all-in-one touchscreen gaming PC and I've never had this happen before.

Update:

In blender it's just the model, I'm not making a movie, I'm just working on a 3D model for a game so the only thing in that scene is the model itself.

Update 2:
For some reason, the model file isn't doing it anymore. I deleted the armature, then brought it back with [ctrl] Z and now it's running normally :/ I can't access the console without starting blender so I can't check it but it would be nice to know why it did this in the first place.

Comment: Does this happen with any other file? If you hit Ctrl+Q what does the small box opening show as hotkey (the right side of the box)?

Comment: Check if this happen only on that pc, or if it happens on a fresh blender zip file. If only that particular file seems to have that problem, I would try to open a fresh new file, and import relevant objects from the problematic file, one by one, checking every time what is causing the right click issue... fixing, though, could be near to impossibile...

Comment: Is this scene very complex? Blender will take a long time to detect the object if the scene gets too complex, and it may get killed by the OS

Comment: This is not intended behavior, under no circumstances should any well behaving application close unexpectedly. It is likely a bug and should probably be reported as a bug to the tracker, although without an example file it might be difficult to reproduce the problem. See if you can recreate the problem with a simpler file you are willing to upload

Comment: @Rawcal It seems to just be this file/model that's doing it. I'll upload a screenshot of that small box when I get home.

Comment: @m.ardito I'm pretty sure it's the model itself but I'll give that a try and see if it works :)

Comment: you could start blender from a console, at least this would print out the last error message before Blender closes. Could point you the right way. So open a console first, navigate to the Blender folder, and start it from there. The console will stay open after the crash.